how would I convert a vim mapping to a neovim mapping?
I need vim for taking notes for math in highschool and I have a bind for vim to launch a script for making inkscape figures.
inoremap <C-f> <Esc>: silent exec '.!inkscape-figures create "'.getline('.').'" "'.b:vimtex.root.'/figures/"'<CR><CR>:w<CR

how would I convert this into a neovim lua keymap.
I have looked online and have struggled to find a solution and I'm really new to using vim / neovim

What did you try?

Possible duplicate Converting conditional vimscript mapping into lua (neovim) (submit  in lua)

Check out :help vim.keymap.set(). That will take you to a reference in the lua.txt help file.
Here is one of the examples from the help file:
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>w', "<cmd>w<cr>", { silent = true, buffer = 5 })

The general form is set({mode}, {lhs}, {rhs}, {opts})
You might need to try escaping some quotes, but it could be something like this
vim.keymap.set('i', '<c-f>', "<Esc>: silent exec '.!inkscape-figures create "'.getline('.').'" "'.b:vimtex.root.'/figures/"'<CR><CR>:w<CR", { silent = true, noremap = true })


Just as Parker Tailor said above.
The Neovim lua keymap, for binding keymaps in your config,
you need to use the vim.keymap.set() function or the vim.api.{func}({...}) utility.
You will get the most of what you need to know in the help docs by running :h vim.keymap.set() and :h vim.api commands.
Look at what the help docs say about vim.api, -
vim.api.{func}({...})                                                
    Invokes Nvim |API| function {func} with arguments {...}.
    Example: call the "nvim_get_current_line()" API function: 

        print(tostring(vim.api.nvim_get_current_line()))

Few Examples:
-- Basic keymap
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>n", vim.cmd.enew, {desc="new file"})

-- calling the "nvim_set_keymap()" api function
-- to map Ctrl+C to - copy to clipboard option
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("v", "<C-c>", ":w !xclip -i -sel c<CR><CR>", { noremap = true })

Just a Suggestion :- If you use which-key plugin in your config, add desc = "description of the keymap" in the {opts} table.
So, the lua representation of the keybinding you want will be -
vim.keymap.set('i', '<c-f>', "<Esc>: silent exec '.!inkscape-figures create "'.getline('.').'" "'.b:vimtex.root.'/figures/"'<CR><CR>:w<CR", { desc="create inkscape figure", silent = true, noremap = true })

